# Switching Domain Registrars with Azure Web App CNAMES

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, subdomain

I'm changing domain registrars for a custom domain that has 4 sub-domains each pointing to a azure web app via a CNAME.

I don't have any access to this azure web app.

Does anybody know if I can just copy the subdomain cname dns and replicate it on the new domain registrar and then everything will continue to work as normal. Or if azure somehow detects the change and requires you to revalidate the domain after you have switched registrars.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not changing sub-domain / domain ONLY the registrar, there should't be any problem with that. Azure App Service doesn't care what register you are using as long as CNAME is properly configured.